# Topological "Interpolation" ?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, open-problems, banach-spaces

Let *E* be a normed space, and let $T$:*E* <sup>*</sup>  $\rightarrow$ *E* <sup>*</sup> be
a nonlinear operator.

Suppose that :

1) $T$ is continuous from (*E* <sup>*</sup>, ||.||) to itself (i.e., it is *norm*-continuous).

and

2) $T$ is continuous from (*E* <sup>*</sup>, *w* <sup>*</sup>) to itself (i.e., it is  *weakly-star* continuous).

Then does it follow that

3) $T$ is continuous from (*E* <sup>*</sup>, *w*) to itself (i.e., it is  *weakly* continuous) ?

---

I guess the case *E* = ℓ∞ would be particularly interesting.

Comment: Ady, is your interest in $\ell_\infty$ because it is a Grothendieck space whose dual unit ball is not weak* sequentially compact?

Comment: Very true. :-) Indeed. Mainly because it is Grothendieck (and with Dunford-Pettis). I just cannot see a counterexample here.


Answer (score 9):

I think Ady's question has a negative answer.

Recall that  the Mazur map, $T$,  from the unit ball of $\ell_2$ onto the unit ball of $\ell_1$, is defined by 
$T(\sum a_i e_i)= \sum a_i^2 b_i   e_i$, where $b_i$ is the sign of $a_i$. It is a uniform homeomorphism in the norm topologies and obviously is coordinatewise continuous, which means that it is weak ($=$ weak$*$ in $\ell_2$) to weak$^*$ continuous (since on the unit ball of $\ell_p$ with $p$ finite  the 
weak* topology is the topology of coordinatewise convergence).
$T$  is not weak to weak continuous since the unit vector basis converges weakly to zero in $\ell_2$ but not in $\ell_1$.

The problem is to extend $T$ to all of $\ell_2$.  I think that the easiest way to do this is to show that there is a retraction $R$ from $\ell_2$ onto its unit ball which is both norm to norm continuous and weak to weak continuous.  Define $R$ on the complement of the unit ball by

$$
R(\sum a_i e_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i + t e_{n+1},
$$
where $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \le 1 < \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i^2$ and $t$ is chosen to have the same sign as $a_{n+1}$ and to make the image vector have norm one.  $R$ is obviously continuous (even Lipschitz)  in the norm topology and is continuous in the topology of coordinatewise convergence, hence is weak to weak continuous (since in all of $\ell_2$, the weak topology is stronger than the topology of coordinatewise convergence).

To get a counterexample that maps one dual space to itself, work with the space $\ell_2 \oplus \ell_1$.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It seems that your construction heavily relies on Schur.
Therefore, may I ask: do you think that the answer is negative for all nonreflexive
spaces, including the quasi-reflexive ones ? E.g., what about E = J, the James space ?

Comment: Any non reflexive space with a basis has a normalized basis that does not converge weakly to zero, but I don't know a replacement for the Mazur map even for J. My guess is that the answer is negative for all non reflexive dual spaces, but my guesses have a probability of only around 1/2 of being correct.